# in bash, "for;do echo;done" splits lines at spaces

Tags: macos, bash, echo

In bash on Mac OSX, I have a file (test case) that contains the lines

```
x xx xxx
xxx xx x
```

But when I execute the command

```
for i in `cat r.txt`; do echo "$i"; done
```

the result is not

```
x xx xxx
xxx xx x
```

as I want but rather

```
x
xx
xxx
xxx
xx
x
```

How do I make echo give me 'x xx xxx'?

Comment: awk 'gsub(/ /,"\n") {print}'
or
sed 's/ /\n/g'

Answer (score 36, accepted):

By default, a Bash for loop splits on all whitespace.  You can override that by setting the `IFS` variable:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for i in `cat r.txt`; do echo "$i"; done
unset IFS
```

Comment: perhaps point the OP towards using `while read; do ...; done < r.txt` instead.

Comment: perfect. thank you. I had looked at the 'while' method but I had other issues with it that seemed much more difficult to overcome than this echo issue.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: the `while read` version does *not* run in a subshell (unless run as e.g. `somecommand | while read ...`, but there the subshell is due to the pipe, not the loop).

Answer (score 3):

Either setting `IFS` as suggested or use `while`:

```
while read theline; do echo "$theline"; done <thefile
```

Comment: It's not the efficiency I was thinking about.  Instead, I was thinking about the problem of variable scope (variables are not shared between "inside" and "outside" the loop).

Comment: Well, yes. But the OP's example didn't call for that ;)

Comment: Please *do* use double-quotes around `$theline` in the echo command, or else it'll convert all tabs and runs of spaces into single spaces.  Also, this does *not* run anything in a subshell.  From some quick tests I did, it looks like the `while read...` option runs faster on files with long lines, and `for ...` runs faster on files with short lines (or I may be mistaking the cause of the variation; I haven't isolated the possible causes well at all).

Comment: "it'll convert all tabs and runs of spaces into single spaces" -- oops! Good point! Haven't thought of that...

Comment: You might want to use `read -r` to keep backslashes in the data read etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
IFS="\n"
for i in `cat r.txt`; do echo "$i"; done
unset IFS
```

Comment: @OliCharlesworth incidentally, as I was testing your answer I accidentally left out the $ and typed exactly what Arenielle has here. It worked.

Although now as I run it on more involved data I see that there are other side effects apparently.

Comment: @atheaos: Are you sure?  `"\n"` in Bash is not the same as in C.  Try changing your `echo` statement to e.g. `echo "LINE: $i"` to see what's really going on.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Huh? Are you still using bash 2.x? 
More than 5 years've passed since bash started to recognize \n sequence in IFS even if it wasn't escaped.

Comment: @Arenielle: I tested on Bash 3.2.25 (that's what happens to be on a test server at work as part of its Centos 5 install).  You may well be correct about it being supported in later versions, but clearly that's not universal!

Comment: @Arenielle: If you edit your question to clarify that this works for GCC > x.x.x, I'll gladly convert my downvote into an upvote...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Works for me even on 3.2.24.

Comment: I just tried with Bash 4.2, and it doesn't work.  Can you point me at the release notes or something that documents the change in behaviour?

Comment: It doesn't work for me (i.e. it splits the file on "n" or "\", not on newlines) under both bash v3.2.48 or v4.2.10.

Comment: Works on Bash 5.0.3 the same as it does with `IFS=$\n"` for me.